# Can't get value from SQL Server made from ASCII values correctly

Tags: java, sql, string, vb6, ascii

Ok, I've searched for this, but haven't found a solution that fits my problem. So here it goes, I'm doing a Java App that connects to a SQL SERVER database used by another application made in Visual Basic 6.

The VB6 application has a routine that "encrypts" a String, the resulting String is an array of chars from 0 to 255 of ascii code and stores it as String in the database in a CHAR(20) column.

Example of such string would be

```
Xj‚[m…^˜
```

However when I try to use that string in Java I expect the third char to give me a value of 130 as it's ASCII value but the following code outputs 8218

```
String test = rs.getString("COLUMN")
System.out.println("ASCII VALUE: "+(int)test.charAt(3))
```

Outputs

```
ASCII VALUE: 8218
```

Now, I'm thinking it's an encoding problem, but I've tried different encodings (Cp1252, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8) and still no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

```
String test = new String(rs.getBytes("COLUMN"), "ISO-8859-1")
```

worked for that particular example, however when I try another example it fails miserably.

Now, I'm assuming what I found out is that the encoding is similar or is ISO-8859-1, if it is that encoding what's the correct way of receiving the String?

Comment: You will need to know at some point what was the encoding used when inserting the data... it may be different from the database encoding, making things more complex (as always when dealing with encoding...)

Comment: the collation for the column is Modern_Spanish_CI_AS, as for the encoding they used, When I asked they didn't even know what encoding was, so I'm guessing they used default encoding.

Comment: How you know string is "Xj‚[m…^˜"?

Comment: I can see it in that format in both the VB6 application and in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio when getting the value for that column manually.

Comment: And how many characters and bytes does it represent in SQL server?

Comment: it represents 9 characters (some could not be displayed here)

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I did have the right encoding, just converted it the wrong way

I was trying to get it like this

```
String text = new String(rs.getString("COLUMN").getBytes("ISO-8859-1")
```

when I should've done this

```
String text = new String(rs.getBytes("COLUMN"), "ISO-8859-1")
```

EDIT:

worked for that particular example, but was not the solution >.<